# Is it possible to add WillCascadeOnDelete to one side of a many to many relationship

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I have the following model:

```
public class List
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ListRules> ListRule { get; set; }
}

public class ListRule
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List List { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<List> Lists { get; set; }
}
```

A List can have many ListRules. A ListRule has to belong to one list. A ListRule can also have 0, 1 or many Lists associated with it.

I tried the following bindings:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ListRule>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.List)
            .WithMany(x => x.ListRule)
            .Map(x => x.MapKey("ListId"));
modelBuilder.Entity<ListRule>()
            .HasMany(x => x.Lists)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(x => {
                          x.MapLeftKey("ListRuleId");
                          x.MapRightKey("ListId");
                          x.ToTable("ListRuleLists");
                      });
```

Before we go further, I woudl like to clarify the result I am looking for:

When someone deletes a List I want the cascade delete constraints to automatically delete the relationships associated with the List in the ListRule table as well as the many to many relationships between ListRule and ListRuleLists tables.

When I try to Update-Database, I get a error saying "FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_ListRuleLists_Lists_ListId' on table 'ListRuleLists' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths." I understand why this is and currently one way to solve it is by adding a WillCascadeOnDelete(false) to the first model binding above.

But this creates an undesired side effect. Let's assume that there is one List with one ListRule with no many-to-many relationships in the ListRuleList table. If a user deletes a List, the ListRule will now be orphaned because of the WillCascadeOnDelete(false).

How can I go about adding the WillCascadeOnDelete(false) to the RightKey side of the second binding instead? In other words, I want to remove the cascade delete from the foreign key constraint "FK_ListRuleLists_Lists_ListId".

Is it possible? If not, are there any other ways to solve this issue?

Comment: To make sure this is clear: so you want to _delete_ the ListRule when it becomes an orphan?

Comment: When a list is deleted, the cascade should delete the foreign key associations in ListRule and the ListRule foreign key associations ListRuleLists. When a ListRule is deleted the cascade should delete the foreign key associations in the ListRuleList table.

Comment: @Thomas - Did you ever find a way to do this?  I'm struggling with the exact same issue.

Comment: One possible solution: create an entity with many "List" and many "List Rule" and then add the cascade for that entity.